# Nginx and Django: How to span a location across multiple paths

Tags: django, nginx

In my Django project,  I have static folders for each app, app1/static/, app2/static, etc. It works fine with the development server.

However when I switch to use Django development server + nginx through fastcgi. There's a problem that I can only map /static to one location. Is it possible, in Nginx,  to map app1/static/, app2/static, etc to url /static.

The following config does not seem to work. What's the correct way to achieve it? Thanks

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    root "app1/static/";app2/static;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/.

What it says is that you serve your files from `static/` sub-folders in your app-folders. In your templates you use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` or in older versions `{% get_static_prefix %}`. In debug mode under the development server Django will directly serve the files from the `static` sub-folders in your app-folders.

When you switch to nginx, you run `collectstatic` as Aviral suggests. This collects all files from the `static/` sub-folders into the `STATIC_ROOT` folder. In order to not have all files in one folder, I would suggest to use `static/app-name` folders in your apps. In this case `STATIC_ROOT` will be populated with distinct `app-name` sub-folders and the static files for each app are separated. The templates must  refer to files like `{{ STATIC_URL }}/app-name/my_static_image.jpg`.

Your nginx config should than simply look like:

```
location ^~ /static {
     root <your STATIC_ROOT path>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've read that link before. But re-reading with your answer makes more sense to me. I finally understand what STATIC_ROOT is used for now.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I don't know much about nginx but I don't think you need to do that and the reason is that the `manage.py collectstatic` command automatically copies all of your static files into one directory (STATIC_ROOT) for you. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'd like to keep each app independent with its own static sub-folders, because the project is just for  learning purpose, all apps inside are actually irrelevant from each other.

Comment: You can still use staticfiles: AppDirectoriesFinder collects the files from the static-dir of each app (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders).

Comment: Yes, that what I am using with the development server. But problem arises when working with Nginx: the static files for app2 cannot be accessed. please see my updates in the question.

Comment: I finally understand the way you suggest is the most correct and natural way to go. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

just tried this on a test server-

```
test directory structure
/home
    /username
        /static_test1
            test1.txt
            style.css
        /static_test2
            test2.txt
            style.css

#nginx.conf
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /home/username;
        try_files /static_test1$uri /static_test2$uri =404;
    }
}
```

If i go to example.com/test1.txt I get the contents of test1.txt and it also works for test2. But it doesn't have any sort of autoindex page, if you don't call the right file you get a Nginx 404.

I don't know if this is the best thing to be doing in production.

Credit to [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/256677/how-to-configure-multiple-root-for-nginx), I just tested it to make sure it works.

**My main concern with this:**
Files with the same name. They get pulled from the first listed directory.

If you are consistent with filenaming across apps/projects this could be a huge problem. For example, style.css would be pulled from static_test1

You really might want to think about the way you want to host static files. As others have mentioned. Django's static file handling as of v1.3 does exactly what you need in one command-[`manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic). It syncs all your app static folders to one centralized folder for hosting.

Comment: Yours and others' answers above have taught me that collectstatic is the best way to go. Although I can only accept one answer, I do have learned from all of you. Thanks.